# my npx react-native run-android build fails

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, dependencies, react-native-camera

My colleague recently added `react-native-camera` to my project. I merged the code and when i run `npx react-native run-android` my build fails with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-camera.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot choose between the following variants of project :react-native-camera:
          - generalDebugRuntimeElements
          - mlkitDebugRuntimeElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'generalDebugRuntimeElements' capability Rombot:react-native-camera:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'generalDebug' but wasn't required.
                  - Found react-native-camera 'general' but wasn't required.
              - Compatible attributes:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Variant 'mlkitDebugRuntimeElements' capability Rombot:react-native-camera:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'mlkitDebug' but wasn't required.
                  - Found react-native-camera 'mlkit' but wasn't required.
              - Compatible attributes:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
```

I have tried to remove my node modules and then do a `npm install` but i still get the same error. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try npx jetify before building?

Comment: try "react-native run-android" only to build

Comment: I just tried jetify and i get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Remove React-Native-Camera dependency and install again and the. Run

> `cd android`

```
./gradlew clean
```

And run app again

Answer (score 0):

Some times `auto-link` feature from `react-native-cli` fails.

Try to link the library manually. Follow these steps....

1. `npm install --save react-native-camera@git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera.git`
2. `react-native link react-native-camera`
3. `npx react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

The same issue has been take care here:

["Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0." -REACT-NATIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61099048/deprecated-gradle-features-were-used-in-this-build-making-it-incompatible-with)

Add this line in `android/app/build.gradle`

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general' <-- insert this line
  }
}
```

After this if you get this error: **“Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug' react-native”**

Refer this link:

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/Execution+failed+for+task+%27%3Aapp%3AmergeDexDebug%27+react-native

Answer (score 0):

use the following command

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then go to the android folder by running

```
cd android
```

then run

```
 ./gradlew clean
```

then run

```
npx react-native link react-native-camera
```

lastly run your project

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this line in ./android/app/build.gradle:

defaultConfig {
...
missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
}

Answer (score 0):

Insert this line in ./android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```